# Cannot mount ISO in CentOS 7 Guest running rescue kernel

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox, iso, rescuemode

I have a CentOS 7-Minimal VM running on a Windows 7 host that has been happily running for a year or so.  A kernel panic occurred and I was unable to boot into anything except the rescue kernel.  While trying to troubleshoot the panic, I removed (via yum remove) all the other installed kernels and was going to simply reinstall the latest.

However, for some reason I cannot mount any ISO file (CentOS, VBox GuestAdditions, etc) to install the kernel package.

Attempting to mount an ISO doesn't recognize the file system:

[image: mount error]

The drive is attached:
[image]

I hope I am missing something simple, but I've spent half a day trying to get this working to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed missing a simple solution.  I attached the CentOS install disk in the VM and booted from it.  When the installer started, I dropped to a command prompt, mounted the /boot partition and coped the kernel RPMs from the installer partition.  I then rebooted into rescue mode, installed the kernel packages with YUM, and was finally able to reboot into a non-rescue kernel.